# Xiaomi Redmi 3 and ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I've recenlty buyed the Xiaomi Redmi 3 for Android development but I have the following issue. The USB debugging is turned on, the ADB is connected. But when I try to install the APK file by typing the

```
adb install my.apk
```

I receive the following message:

```
/system/bin/pm[6]: app_process: not found
```

And nothing happens. When I try to install it from Android Studio it shows just like it running the app, but nothing is happening. Maybe someone have experience with dealing with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that by rooting the device. Don't know why it helps but I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rooting it, try this:

1. Go to Settings --> Additional Settings --> Privacy
2. Enable "Unknown Sources (Allow installation of apps from unknown sources)" option

Then try installing it. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

Is the app listed as installed on your phone?

If it is, try uninstalling it and running install command again.

Comment: No, it is not listed as installed.